# vim - show whitespace for selection only

Tags: vim, whitespace

Is it possible to show whitespace characters (space, tabs, newlines) only in visual mode, specifically in the selected text?

Or is there already a nice plugin that does the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how the highlighting is set up for visual mode, it is possible to set the foreground color of your white space characters to the background color of the window.

- This is a sample `Normal` highlight group (taken from my own colorscheme) which defines the background color of the whole window:

  ```
  hi Normal ctermbg=235 ctermfg=250 guibg=#262626 guifg=#bcbcbc cterm=NONE gui=NONE
  ```

  The values we want are `235` for color terminals and `#262626` for the GUI.
- This is a sample `Visual` highlight group. It's only one foreground color on one background color:

  ```
  hi Visual ctermbg=110 ctermfg=235 guibg=#8fafd7 guifg=#262626 cterm=NONE gui=NONE
  ```

  The colors themselves don't really matter.
- This is how we could set up the `SpecialKey` highlight group, using the values above:

  ```
  hi SpecialKey ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=235 guibg=NONE guifg=#262626 cterm=NONE gui=NONE
  ```

  And this is how it should look:

  [image]

You'll need to edit your colorscheme for this to work across the board or to add this to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup colors
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * hi SpecialKey ctermfg=235 guifg=#262626
  autocmd ColorScheme * hi NonText    ctermfg=235 guifg=#262626
augroup END
```

Of course, the colors above are are just an example; YMMV.

Comment: awesome. What i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The "list" option in Vim will show whitespace characters:

> List mode: Show tabs as CTRL-I is displayed, display $ after end of
>   line.  Useful to see the difference between tabs and spaces and for
>   trailing blanks.

See:

```
:help list
```

That being said...

This isn't exactly what you want, but [Tim Pope's unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) provides a very easy way to toggle off the "list" option (among many other options).

When the

So, if you need to take a quick glance at those whitespace characters you can toggle them on/off with:

```
col
```

I consider unimpaired an essential, very light-weight plugin (basically just a set of mappings)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.
But want I actually want is to know if it is possible to view whitespace chars in selected text. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, to permantly switch the display of the visual selection to enable the `list` mode, while the rest of the buffer does not have `list` set.

A workaround however is, after visually selecting some lines, press <kbd>:</kbd> so the command line looks like this: `:'<,'>` and then just use the `:list` command (which can be shortened to `:l`). So using `:'<,'>l` will echo the selected range of lines as if the list setting has been turned on. This however works only linewise, so it is not possible to only print the block selected region.

See the help at `:h :l`.